# Нужно ли вставлять дополнительный предлог "у", как вам кажется?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Развитые страны перестали быть «основным покупателем» энергоресурсов, поскольку темпы роста развивающихся экономик выше, чем (у) развитых. 
Кажется, что здесь где-то просится предлог "у", но не могу понять, где...

Comment: Вопросы с целью выяснить то, что Вас интересует, @Alenka, уже задавались здесь. [Вот](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/29295/синтаксис-как-правильнее), например. Возможно, Вам будет интересно изучить предложенные ответы.

Comment: @Alenka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы оставила следующий вариант: "Развитые страны перестали быть «основным покупателем» энергоресурсов, поскольку темпы роста развивающихся экономик выше, чем у развитых".

Темпы роста экономики - это обычное терминологическое сочетание, "темпы роста у экономики" - ошибочное выражение по отношению к подобным словам.

А вот во втором случае ("чем у развитых") предлог "У" желателен  в связи с неполным составом сравнительного оборота, без этого предлога смысл предложения не читается ясно.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь предлог не нужен.
Он был бы оправданным, в конструкции типа *"...поскольку темпы роста **у** развивающихся экономик выше, чем **у** развитых"*. Но этот вариант сам по себе несколько просторечный, "темпы роста экономики (такой-то страны)" в строгом стиле речи предлога не требует.

Так что оставляейте как есть, без предлогов.

Comment: Спасибо. Хотя мне больше нравится ваш вариант с предлогами.